# how to find the top 3 most-wanted waterskis, ordered in descending order by number of offers made;

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT waterski.id 
FROM images (
    SELECT DISTINCT offer 
    FROM offer a 
    WHERE 3 <= (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT offer) FROM offer b WHERE b.offer >= a.offer
    ) 
    ORDER BY a.offer DESC"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT waterski.id FROM images (
    SELECT DISTINCT offer 
    FROM offer a 
    WHERE 3 <= (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT offer) FROM offer b WHERE b.offer >= a.offer) 
    ORDER BY a.offer DESC"
);
```

[image]